# How can i create a separate chunk for each component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want a plugin which can create a separate chunk for each of my components.

Is there any existing plugin in **Webpack** where I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins) for chunking in Webpack, but there is no option for such division out of the box. Anyway, why do you need it at all?

Comment: Actually, we need common chunk which would capture all the common dependency code in one place, so where it's required we could use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Chunk per build not per component, say you have three different build app, pollyfills, vendor. Then you can use CommonsChunckPlugin for your those builds like this

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
})
```

Comment: Thanks @mrJSingh .i will try to implement in this approach ! can u provide me some example for  this please?

Comment: This might be outdated. I think it's the  `config.optimization.splitChunks` configuration, or the `SplitChunksPlugin`?